# Multiple forms with iput fields with the same name attribute

Tags: jquery, html, web.py

I have a form with multiple inputbox in it. And mutil clone with this form.

How can I insert all form into db with web py?

This is clone code:

```
function resetForm($$form) {
    $$form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $$form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
var count = 0;
var $$clonedata = $$('.form_data').clone();
resetForm($$clonedata);
$$(document).on('click', '.Add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    $$clonedata.clone().appendTo('#form_data').attr('id','form_data');
  });

$$('#form_data').on('click', '.Remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $$(this).closest('.form_data').remove();
});
```

Comment: If you show you HTML then it would be easy to help you for all SO users.

Comment: <div id="form_data" class="form_data" style="margin:5px">
<input type="text" name="name1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="name2" value=""/>
<button class="Remove">Remove</button>
</div>

Comment: I think your question could look *much* better with only a little [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163). Look, how well it looks after my edit. Also you could do it. Btw, it is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this like,

```js
$(function() {
  function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
  }
  var count = 0;
  var $clonedata = $('.form_data').clone();
  resetForm($clonedata);
  $('.Add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    $clonedata.clone().appendTo('#form_data').attr('id', 'form_data');
  });

  $('#form_data').on('click', '.Remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.form_data').remove();
  });
  
  $('.Save').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($('form').serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<a class="Add" href="#">Add</a>
<div id="form_data">
  <div class="form_data" style="margin:5px"> <input type="text" name="name1[]" value="" /> <input type="text" name="name2[]" value="" /> <button class="Remove">Remove</button>
</div>
</div>
<a class="Save" href="#">Save</a>

</form>
```

Comment: how i can insert all <div name ="form_data> into my database. i can insert only one . my code in py. class add:
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
 n = db.insert('dbname',name1 = i.name1,name 2= i.name2)